# How to map joint index to the corresponding index in generalized positions?

Tags: python-3.x, drake

Given the floatng base pose and a list of joint values ordered by their corresponding joint index, I want to construct a generalized position vector so I can `setPosition` the plant.

I am aware that indices `0` to `7` of the generalized positions corresponds to the floating base pose.  How do I figure out the generalized position index of each joint?  From my experimentation, the generalized position index of joint `i` is not simply `i+7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drake joints all derive from a common Joint base class, documented [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_joint.html). That class has methods [velocity_start()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_joint.html#ae24835fcef569246252959b18d0027d6), num_velocities(), position_start(), num_positions() that provide indexes into the generalized velocity and generalized position vectors.